# Change form exclude value in django after validation

Tags: python, django

I have following form based in model.

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_column='title')
    url = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_column='url')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, db_column='category')
    description = models.TextField(db_column='description')
    createDate = models.DateTimeField(db_column='createDate')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'articles'
        ordering = ['createDate']
```

Form

```
class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('title', 'description', 'category')
```

What I want is to validate form and change value of url by lowercasing cleaned title.
How can I accomplish that?
I appears that url is excluded value, so how can I change it in form after validation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can supply a custom URL when saving an article like this:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.url:
            self.url = self.title.lower()

        super(Article, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: This will work for new instances, but what about editing an existing Article, say to change the title. In that case the URL wouldn't get updated.

Comment: You can remove the `if` statement to always overwrite the URL.

Comment: Thank you this worked. I also found another way. form=Article(request.POST) if form.is_valid(): article=form.save(commit=False) article.url=article.title.lower() article.save()